# Missing Emoji key in latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10-v1703, on-screen-keyboard

I recently updated a Windows 10 tablet to 1703, and on some applications the Emoji button on the onscreen keyboard has been replaced by one that seems to toggle key highlighting when writing.

[image: Screenshot]

Please see attached screenshot. Any idea why this happens, and how can I return the keyboard to how it used to be?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. I found a suggestion to go to the Ease of Access settings and turn on the On-Screen Keyboard from there. I did it and it brought back my Emoji button.

[image]